# Why does firefox always load the next page in the menu as well as the page I have requested?

Tags: firefox, web-applications

I am working on a new website.  While testing some of the functionality I had a number of debug statements and was watching the logs.  It seems that Firefox (at least) loads the "next" page in the menu as well as the page I have clicked on.  If I have menu items A B C D E and click on B then I see a request for mysite.com/B and then a request for mysite.com/C in the logs, and so on.

Is this some kind of look-ahead performance thing?  Is there any way to avoid it (setting an attribute on the link maybe?)  The problem is that the second page in my menu is somewhat heavier as it loads a whole lot of data from a web service.  I'm happy for people to do that if they want to use the functionality, but would rather not that every visitor to the front page loads it unneccessarily.  Is this behvaiour consistent across browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Firefox will prefetch links to improve the perceived performance to the user. You can read more about the functionality in Firefox here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ

It isn't possible to disable this in the client's browser, however the request should include the header `X-moz: prefetch` which you can use to determine if it is in fact a prefetch request or not, and potentially return a blank page for prefetch requests. You can then use `Cache-control: must-revalidate` to make sure the page loads appropriately when actually requested by the user.

If you happen to be using Worpdress for your site, you can disable the  tags with the prefetch information by using:

Wordpress 3.0+

```
//remove auto loading rel=next post link in header
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head');
```

Older versions:

```
//remove auto loading rel=next post link in header
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link');
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I see now that it is the link rel="next" (which wordpress ahd automatically added to the page header) which cause it, so by removing that I should be able to turn this feature off.

Comment: I guessed you were using Wordpress - I edited my answer to include the code that removes the tags from your header, you only need to include the one that is appropriate for your version. Include it in your functions.php

Comment: Thanks, yeah, once we knew what we were looking for we found that code too. have now removed the link :)

Comment: I am creating a plugin and there I need to prevent prefetch. Since I am building a plugin, I can't touch other section (like header) in wordpress.  What is the way to disable prefetching in the plugin.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't call the remove_action listed above from a plugin.  In my case I did it from functions.php in the theme, but the pojunt is it's an action so you can unschedule it from anywhere (you may need to do so in another action so that it runs after the action is set and before it is called)

Comment: The code in my answer can definitely be used in a plugin, that's actually the recommended place for it. The only reasonable option would be `functions.php` but I don't like it for a variety of reasons. To use in a plugin, I would hook a function to the `init` action and then within it call the `remove_action` lines in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called prefetch.  It can be turned off in the client, see the FAQ:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Link_prefetching_FAQ
```

I'm not aware of a way to turn it off via the server